# Total boundedness of $K \subset \ell^1$, iff $K$ is uniformly summable & bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $K \subset \ell^1$ and define *uniform summability* of $K$ such that for any $\varepsilon >0$ exists a natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $x \in K$ the $N$-tail of the series over $x$ is bounded, i.e.  $\sum_{n=N}^\infty|x_n| \le \varepsilon$.

> **Claim:** $K$ is totally bounded, iff $K$ is bounded and uniformly summable.

I was able to show that if $K$ is totally bounded, it is indeed bounded. By assumption $K$ can be covered by a finite number of $\varepsilon$-balls, thus it was easy to construct a ball centered around $0_{\ell^1}$, which covers all of $K$.

Now, under the same assumption, I want to show that $K$ is uniformly summable. By total boundedness of $K$, I know that for any $\delta >0$ and $x \in K$, I can find $y\in K$ such that $\|x-y\|_{\ell^1}< \delta$. I don't know how to translate this fact to an expression, which could be extended to bounding an $N$-tail of the series over $x$.

A hint for the backwards implication of the claim is also appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose $K$ is totally bounded, you want to show that it is uniformly summable: Fix $\epsilon > 0$, then there are finitely many points $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_m\} \subset K$ such that, for each $x\in K$, there is $1\leq i\leq m$ such that
   $$
   \|x-y_i\| < \epsilon
   $$
   For each $1\leq i\leq m$, there exists $N_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
   $$
   \sum_{k=N_i}^{\infty} |y_i(k)| \leq \epsilon
   $$
   Let $N := \max\{N_i : 1\leq i\leq m\}$, then show that, for any $x\in K$,
   $$
   \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} |x(k)| \leq 2\epsilon
   $$
   Hence, $K$ is uniformly summable.
2. Conversely, suppose $K$ is bounded and uniformly summable. You want to show that it is totally bounded. I will give an elaborate hint: Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
   $$
   \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} |x(k)| \leq \epsilon
   $$
   for all $x\in K$. Furthermore, let $M > 0$ such that $\|x\| \leq M$ for all $x\in K$. Now consider the set
   $$
   B := \{(x(1),x(2), \ldots, x(N), 0, 0, \ldots) : x\in K\}
   $$
   This can be thought of as a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, so $B$ is totally bounded. 
   Now try to complete the proof from here.

Comment: For the canonical embedding, $()⊂ℝ^$ is bounded. Hence, for $>0$ exist $_1,…,_∈()$ with $()⊂∪_(_,)$ in $\left((),|⋅|_1\right)$. For $^{−1}:()→,(_1,…,_)↦(_1,…,_,0,0…)$, we have $^{−1}(_) \in $ and for any $y\in B$ holds $\min_‖^{−1}(_)-y‖_{ℓ^1} < \varepsilon$.  Further, for an arbitrary element in $K$, the $$-tail of the series is less or equal to $$.

Comment: So the $\ell^1$-distance between $B$ and $x\in K$ is bounded by $\varepsilon$, as for $x\in K$ we can find an element in $B$ where the first $N$ agree. We are left with $K⊂∪_(^{−1}(_),)$, because with an appropriate choice of $y \in B$, we have that  for all $∈K$ holds $\min_‖^{−1}(_)−‖_{ℓ^1} ≤ \min_‖^{−1}(_)-y‖_{ℓ^1} +‖y-‖_{ℓ^1} < 2$.